# Problem with Climbing Aloe mid-stem drying up

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, watering, container-gardening, aloe

I started this on my window sill 3 years ago. It was a lot bigger than current photo, had to cut off dying. The stems are drying up and dying. I did transplant and moved it from back yard (hotter) to front porch. Gets morning sun and we’re in Vegas so it’s hot and this happened in July, but didn’t happen in prior summer or for 5 months or so on porch, but when got hot it did this? Not sure. Also noticed that roots were exposed at top. Not sure if soil settled or if roots were searching for water. I’m really good about watering several times per week in the summer. Yes I use good organic cactus soil. Photo is of a spot where this starts to happen. I have other stems that seem to wilt mid stem

Comment: Thank you for your question; if could include an overall illustration, & closer illustration of the top & leaves, overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, hours of direct sunlight & hours of diffused light per day, average daytime & average night time temperature, container size, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding images according the instructions which appear. Thank you! Welcome to the site!